# Firebase database rules and permission_denied error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a Firebase database with the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        ".read":  "true",
        ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The data structure looks like this:

[image]

I can write to it without a problem, but when I attempt to read, I get the following error:

```
Error: permission_denied at /messages: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
```

I've read the firebase docs, and my structure looks the same as examples given. Please, can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

Please note: moving the read rule up under "messages" does fix the issue but is not the solution I want as I want to write a rule based on the message data (similar to the write rule) once I have the basic rule working. I want to end up with a rule like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$message": {
        ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
        ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules you have defined at `/messages/$message` do not affect queries made to `/messages` and since you haven't added any read permissions to `/messages`, you are getting permission denied.

If you would like to retrieve messages made by a single user, consider restructuring your data to nest the messages of a user under their uid, e.g.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "user-messages": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        "$mid": {
          ".write": "newData.child('uid').val() === $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With this structure, you can retrieve all the messages a user owns. If you would like to retrieve all messages, then you will also need to write messages to `/messages`. Here you can store the message data, and in `/user-messages/$uid`, you can store the keys for each message the user posts. You can perform both writes simultaneously using multi-location updates).

```
{
  "messages": {
    "a": { "uid": "0", ... },
    "b": { "uid": "0", ... }
  }
  "user-messages": {
    "0": {
      "a": true,
      "b": true
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "0": { ... }
  }
}
```

Get the keys for a user's messages at `user-messages/$uid` and then get each individual message.

Comment: hmmm.. I started off with a structure like that but my problem is that I have two use cases; One where a user gets to see only their own messages, and two where an admin gets to see all messages. The admin query needs to be able to be filtered by attributes such as wether a message is open or closed. When I tried to do this with a more nested structure, I found that writing the admin query was impossible (too much nesting) . Sounds like I'm back to the drawing board... :-(

Comment: So only the admin can see all the messages? and so a user can only see their messages?

Comment: Yes that's right. I have a token that I can identify admin users with. The problem is structing the data so I can query it and users can read their own messages.

Comment: I updated my answer, you will need to do something called fanning out your data.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion was very helpful. I have denormalised the data and have put it into two tables which have different rules and structures.

Comment: A little off topic, but it's worth looking into https://github.com/firebase/bolt to create your database rules. It makes it much easier to write our rules which make sense and are easier to read.